# Datatables child rows form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatable

I am using [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) example but within the child rows, I have a form. The problem is, it's not submitting the input from the child rows if the child rows are closed. Now I see datatables is using: `show()` and `hide()` functions as in this code of their example:

```
if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
```

Now that makes me think it's just hiding it and showing it so when its hidden, it should still be there AND submitted, but it isn't since they are probably using a datatables made function or something. How would I make it that I can actually submit the input fields in the child rows when the child rows are "hidden"? It works fine when I have the row opened.

Comment: check your inspect element and you will find out that the details divs is not a hidden divs, datatable somehow is appending/creating those divs, so it's not about hiding and showing

Comment: also take a look at https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child.hide()

Comment: @hassan So I cant touch the show function cause it actually **creates** the child row and the hide just removes it. If I change the hide to a actual hide, the show function would just create new rows every time it's triggered and never actually remove the ones that arent being used.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately JQuery DataTables doesn't provide any method to get the informations that you need, moreover it removes the hided rows from the DOM.

So, the only thing you could do is to store the modified values in detail rows in some variable and read them on submit, see following please:

```js
var dataSet = [
    {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Tiger Nixon",
    "position" : "Edinburgh",
    "salary" : "5421"
    },
    {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Ludovico Moro",
    "position" : "Milan",
    "salary" : "8670"
    },
    {
    "id" : 3,
    "name" : "Julio Iglesias",
    "position" : "Madrid",
    "salary" : "12500"
    }
];

var fullnames = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            {
                "className": 'details-control',
                "orderable": false,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
    
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
    
} );

function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" class="fullname" id="' + d.id + '" value="' + d.name + '" onchange="javascript:inputChange(this.id, this.value)"></td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$("#form1").submit(function( event ) {
  $.each(fullnames, function(index, value){
    if(fullnames[index]){
      console.log("Modified record " + index + ", new value is: " + value);
    }
  });
  event.preventDefault();  
});

function inputChange(id, val){
  fullnames[id] = val;
}
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="form1">
  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
          <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
      </tfoot>
  </table>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

To sum up:

1) Declare a global var to store the fullnames

```
var fullnames = [];
```

2) In the function `format`, add onchange listener to the input box

```
onchange="javascript:inputChange(this.id, this.value)"
```

3) Create the listener

```
function inputChange(id, val){
  fullnames[id] = val;
}
```

4) Finally, read its values on submit

```
$.each(fullnames, function(index, value){
        if(fullnames[index]){
          console.log("Modified record " + index + ", new value is: " + value);
        }
      });
```

Obviously instead of a fullnames array you can save an array of objects containing all the fields you need.

I hope it helps you, bye.